# Cannot combine results from different renderlayers?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am trying to very simply use the compositor, but keep running into the same problems over and over.

I have tried both in Cycles and Blender Internal, but to no avail.
When I move a sphere to a new layer, split the render layers into two, one with everything but the ball, and one with the ball, this happens:

[image]

Just a black and flat circle with the blur in compositing.
In cycles I cannot even combine the two:

[image]

I have tried following every tutorial out there, but it's still the same, leading me to think it's something to do with my blender setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Blender Internal:

The reason the sphere is black is because the lamps are only on layer 1, but not on the sphere layer.

You can move objects to more than one layer at once by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking on the layers on which you want to make the selected object(s) visible.

[image]

## Cycles:

Try enabling *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved many coming hours of frustration :)