# I have two layers with different objects in an animation how do I render these two layers together?

Tags: animation, render-layers, layers

Question pretty much says it all. Also one more question: in the place where you can click on the layers there is a gold dot in one of the slots and a grey dot in another slot does the gold dot mean that layer will be rendered because the grey dot layer is not being rendered?
Thanks!

Comment: The gold dot refers to the layer which contains the active object. To define the layers used for rendering, you'll need to setup renderlayers. To combine rendered layers, you could try a Z-combine node.

Comment: It's hard to say what you'll need to do without more info. Could you explain your setup, maybe with some screenshots or a .blend? Related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7907/599

Answer (score 1):

To activate more than one layer, you need to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> the layer buttons in the *3D-View Header* or the *Render Layers*, or you can press the appropriate number on the top row of your keyboard (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>,... for the top row, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>... for the bottom) To select all press <kbd>`</kbd>.

The darker buttons are visible layers, and the lighter ones invisible.

The dots in the layer buttons indicate that they contain at least one object. The layer that contains the active object will have an orange dot instead of a grey one.

[image: Layers]

[Documentation of Layer Settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Post_Process/Layers#Scene_Layers_Settings)